# When setting CSS hover queries, how can I override CDN derived hover rules?

Tags: html, css, hover, media-queries, touch

I've been wrapping CSS hover queries within media query selectors as follows:

```
@media (hover: hover), screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .btn-primary:hover {
        ...
    }
}
```

This ensures that no sticky hovers persist on touch devices (the -ms prefixes are for IE11).

However, as my sites make use of CDN hosted libraries such as Bootstrap, **the hover rules from that library are now persisting**, as they are not enclosed in such a query. I've now effectively moved the problem out of my codebase, but cannot get rid of these CDN derived rules.

I had previously made use of Modernizr to add the `[no-]touchevents` classes to the body, but version 3.7 onwards seems to have issues in how best to detect touch or non touch devices, hence the rationale behind this change.

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem, despite copious searches on StackOverflow and across Google. A lot of searches reveal solutions from some time ago, certainly nothing that matches this problem.

I've added a Codepen to show this problem - https://codepen.io/sassquad/full/f0b120dbd51c5f1857c24ff6d78ddb80

Any 'pointers' are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: From the top off my head: Either use the same rules in your in-document CSS, override the values and add '!important' to the attribute value. Like `some-cdn-rule:hover { ... !important }` or use inline styles doing the same `<div style="...">` (but that won't work with :hover.) Essentially you need to make sure that your rules have 'higher' precedence than the CDN rules....

Comment: But make sure you add [reprex] so we can (what CDN? your specific code CSS/HTML) figure out a workaround. Now you are being way to generic, which will yield little SO response or downvotes.... (shoot, I meant '...preference...' before, or both, dunno)

Comment: This is pretty much a specificity question - you just need to make sure your rules are more specific than the rules in the cdn - if you are always wanting it to be overriden in the same way then using `!important` with `*:hover` here is probably ok as you won't be wanting to use different styles and get into an `!important` nightmare.  If you don't want to use important, then you will need to find all your hover selectors and copy them into your override media query

Comment: A reason for not doing anything like that: you used CDN code for a reason. It comes with its own set of do's/don'ts and specific rules. Go with those and adjust you code following those rules or don't use that specific CDN code. Choices....

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've added a Codepen demo, if you are using Chrome, you can switch the view to iPad emulated view. Click the button to show the unwanted state coming from the CDN hosted Bootstrap 3 library.

Comment: @rene-van-der-lende - I've added commented out !important attributes. My testing suggests this is the only approach possible, despite my dislike of doing this.

Comment: There you go, you made your choice. Just remember for your own code: `!important` is a good way to make absolutely sure some value is used (until some other CSS or JS overrides that. Injected code can be nasty like that), but I prefer not to use it or as a last resort...

Comment: @Rene-van-der-Lende I can't seem to find an alternative to the use of !important. As much as I resent it, this appears to be a hidden gotcha when using a combination of local styles within such media queries upon a framework hosted via CDN. I would love to be proved wrong, but until then, I've upvoted your suggestion.

Comment: Final comment: I think this is not an issue about whether or not to use `!important`, but whether an external library (like bootstrap) is the one you need (I cannot decide that for you). And (hint) you can always copy the bootstrap.css, modify it to your needs and serve that version as an alternative. It's you page after all, do what you need to do....